# Is there a jQuery or plain javascript plug-in that uses XHR upload progress feedback primarly and flash as an alternative?

Tags: javascript, ajax, plugins, upload, progress

FF4 and Chrome have a built in support for upload progress feedback via ajax. I'm looking for a plugin that uses that method if available and a flash alternative if the browser is older. Do you know any such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script works well for ajax uploading http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Comment: I've seen this before but these cfm and cfc files are very confusing to me. Could i use this on apache?

Comment: Yes, The cfc files are coldfusion files but you don't need them, assuming you're using PHP you only need the php.php file from the server directory. It's very simple to use.

Comment: Hey thanks man now i get it and have been able to set it up into one of my controllers. It seems to be working pretty well for now.